# Find the number of components in the current fill & stroke color space form CGContext?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-2d, macos-carbon

I am looking at way of finding the color space of a `CGContext`?

`CGBitmapContextGetColorSpace()` will not work as I am working with general context and not bitmap context.

Thank you,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

colorspaceref CGContextGetStrokeColorSpace(ccontextref);

colorspaceref CGContextGetFillColorSpace(ccontextref);

but this are priate.

Comment: I believe for now I can go with some private stuff. THanks

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any way to retrieve this information; for a system-provided CGContext, the color space actually used may not even be any of the publicly-defined color spaces.

There also does not seem to be any way to retrieve the current fill or stroke color or color space. But there also does not seem to be any documented restriction on the types of colors that may be passed to `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` or `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor`, so in general you should just set the color you want and let the framework handle translating that into the appropriate format for the CGContext.

Comment: I need to get this color space from one context to other. So, I will have to fetch that from context.

Comment: @Rahul: Unfortunately, Apple doesn't seem to provide a way to do that. Except for CGBitmapContexts, CGContexts are generally write-only. Why do you need to fetch the color space, anyway? Perhaps there is a different way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I know Apple does not provide any public API to read these details out of context. I am just trying to create a context which does exactly the same things other context does. Now if somebody calls `CGContextSetFillColor(CGContextRef c, const CGFloat components[])` on the context, and I dont have components[], I need colorspace to Identify the number of components. I know this all will pop up lots of question in your mind but this what I am trying to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly read colorspace data from CGContext properties. So you'll have to work around this shortcoming in the CGContext API by
 - intercepting property updates on the way **to** the CGContext of interest, or
 - outputting PDF data whose stream you then examine for the colorspace & color data.

Comment: Actually source of this question is interception of property updates on context. Lets say.. if somebody calls CGContextSetFillColor(CGContextRef c, const CGFloat components[]) on the context, in order to read the components[] I need to know the number of components. But how? We cannot determine the size of dynamic array? But if we can find the colorspace we can get the number of components.